# Push to Azure DevOps from Visual Studio with Agile Process as Default

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I connected Azure DevOps to Visual Studio and when I press "Publish Git Repo" everything is working fine.

[image]

But it always creates a Scrum process Dashboard.
I made Agile as default and disabled all of the others in my organisation.

[image]

Now Visual Studio throws this error

```
VS403119: You cannot add a team project with process Scrum as it is disabled. Either choose a different process, or enable process Scrum and try again.
```

[image]

So it means the setting is somewhere in Visual Studio.

The only thing I found about it is [this two years old question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/229361/process-template-not-selectable-when-publish-git-r.html).

Do you know the setting or some config file to change the default process board when publishing to the Azure DevOps from Visual Studio?

Comment: The post you referenced is still valid, it's actually an API call. Unless there is some settings in Team Explorer before you push I don't think this is possible to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio always specifies `Scrum` process when creating Azure Devops project via its Team Explorer, as I know there's **no** VS settings available to manage this behavior.

As a workaround you can create the project with `Agile` process in web portal first, add local project/solution into source control and choose `Target Project`(Click `Advanced`) before publishing the repo:

[image]

Actually this behavior is VS-specific cause Azure Devops itself supports specifying process template even by [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples). So I decide to post a feature request related to your requirements in User Voice forum with `VS tag` instead of `Azure Devops tag`. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.